# Yii 1 Pagination showing different behaviour in different controllers

Tags: php, pagination, yii1.x

In my Yii application, some controllers returning pagination URL as follows:

```
http://example.com/blog/index?page=2
```

And if I have written the same code in some other controller, then the pagination URL shows as follows:

```
http://example.com/blog/index/page/2
```

Any idea why it showing differently in different controllers? I need the page number as a query string (like the first URL).

Comment: Check your `urlManager` configuration, also you could study the tutorial from https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/final.url and https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination

Comment: But its working fine on another controller (i have copied the action to that controller), without adding any rule for that action to the route file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the issue, I have missed the following rule in my route file, which caused the issue.

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

This should be added as follows:

```
return array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(               
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```